# Why it always replace the first data when i click display?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a little problem with my system, This is my problem when i insert the data, that data will show in `DatagridView`, now if i insert different data again, the first data in the `DatagridView` will remove and will be replace by the second data. Sounds like easy, but I've tried everything like, copy my same code, search to internet, But still got the same problem.

And also i used `Breakpoint` to see where the code going and what to be trigger.

This is my code so far.

```
 If TxtRod_ID.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Please enter RD Code.") : Exit Sub
    If rbRD.Checked = False And rbOSS.Checked = False Then MsgBox("Please select User On.") : Exit Sub

    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim strUser As String = ""
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

    If rbRD.Checked = True Then
        RoDID = TxtRod_ID.Text
        RdGetSrvr()
        cn = New OleDbConnection(RDcon)
        Try
            If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to the database. Please contact the administrator.", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        If rbUserName.Checked = True Then
            If txtFname.Text.Trim() = "" And txtLname.Text.Trim() = "" Then MsgBox("Please enter First and/or Last Name of User.") : Exit Sub
            strUser = "select * from USERS..MS_User where First_Name like '%" & txtFname.Text.Trim() & "%' and Last_Name like '%" & txtLname.Text.Trim() & "%'"

        ElseIf rbUserId.Checked = True Then
            If txtUserID.Text.Trim() = "" Then MsgBox("Please enter User ID.") : Exit Sub
            strUser = "select  * from USERS..MS_User where User_ID like '%" & txtUserID.Text.Trim() & "%'"

        End If
    Else
        If rbUserId.Checked = True Then
            If txtUserID.Text.Trim() = "" Then MsgBox("Please enter User ID.") : Exit Sub

            COGetSrvr()
            cn = New OleDbConnection(COcon)
            cn.Open()
            strUser = "select * from objUsr..user_locked_tbl where UserName like '%" & txtUserID.Text.Trim() & "%'"

        End If
    End If

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(strUser, cn)

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim ctr As Integer = 0
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read
            dgUser.Rows.Add()
            If rbRD.Checked = True Then
                dgUser("dgUserID1", ctr).Value = dr("User_ID")
                dgUser("dgFname1", ctr).Value = dr("First_Name")
                dgUser("dgLname1", ctr).Value = dr("Last_Name")
                dgUser("dgPrimaryRole1", ctr).Value = dr("Primary_Role")
                dgUser("dgUserStatus1", ctr).Value = dr("User_Status")
                dgUser("dgULoginCnt1", ctr).Value = dr("Unsuccessful_Login_Count")
                dgUser("dgDesig1", ctr).Value = dr("Designation")
            Else
                dgUser("dgUserID1", ctr).Value = dr("UserName")
                dgUser("dgFname1", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgLname1", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgPrimaryRole1", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgUserStatus1", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgULoginCnt1", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgDesig1", ctr).Value = ""
            End If
        End While
    Else
        MsgBox("No record found.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

When i add data and click the button display button. The result is ok.

[image: Result 1]

Now if i add data again. The first data will remove and replace by second data.

[image: Result 2]

As you can see in result 2 there is a blank `row`, when i insert this to my code, `dgUser.Rows.Clear`, of course the blank `row` will remove but i got the same problem.

I want to achieve is, if i insert the first data it will not be remove when inserting the second data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the flag “ctr “ is not changed in the loop. 
Is it a about the row number of the result placed, 
So all the result goes to the same place?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Dim ctr As Integer = 0
    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read
            For ctr = 0 To dgUser.Rows.Count - 1
            Next
            dgUser.Rows.Add()
            If rbRD.Checked = True Then
                dgUser("dgUserID", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("User_ID")) = True, "", dr("User_ID"))
                dgUser("dgFname", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("First_Name")) = True, "", dr("First_Name"))
                dgUser("dgLname", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("Last_Name")) = True, "", dr("Last_Name"))
                dgUser("dgPrimaryRole", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("Primary_Role")) = True, "", dr("Primary_Role"))
                dgUser("dgUserStatus", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("User_Status")) = True, "", dr("User_Status"))
                dgUser("dgULoginCnt", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("Unsuccessful_Login_Count")) = True, "", dr("Unsuccessful_Login_Count"))
                dgUser("dgDesig", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("Designation")) = True, "", dr("Designation"))
            Else
                dgUser("dgUserID", ctr).Value = If(IsDBNull(dr("UserName")) = True, "", dr("UserName"))
                dgUser("dgFname", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgLname", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgPrimaryRole", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgUserStatus", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgULoginCnt", ctr).Value = ""
                dgUser("dgDesig", ctr).Value = ""
            End If

            ctr += 1
        End While
```

I got it. I just forgot to insert `For Loop` in my code. Thanks @Terry D for the idea.

Comment: Instead of making an empty loop you can just set `ctr = dgUser.Rows.Count - 1` directly.